# CSS изоляция

Tags: css

Можно ли как-то изолировать отдельную часть страницы от применения глобальных стилей??

в blabla.css у меня есть вот такой вот "класс" :

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Что с делать с тегом (в моем случае <h:outputText>) чтобы он эти стили игнорировал или наверное правильно выразится как его переопределить?
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: поподробнее,что где и как ?

Comment: просто добавьте к элементам class="" ,и дальше пишите определенно для этого элемента

Comment: есть тег <h:outputText value="value"/> Так вот value это html документ и к нему соответственно применяются глобальные стили. class="" пробовал, не помогает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, изолировать часть страницы от глобальных стилей нельзя. Если стиль глобальный и часть страницы подходит под условие тех стилей, они будут применяться.

Стиль можно переопределить. Если вам надо какой-то блок сайта отображать со стилями отличающимися от глобальных - переопределите нужные стили для того блока. Воспользуйтесь вложенностью тэгов или классом и создайте правила стилей для того уникального блока.

**UPD**: согласно [документации](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputText.html) можно добавить inline style.

```
<h:outputText value="value" style="font-weight:bold" />
```

Вот в **style=""** - записать все нужные стили для этого блока.

Comment: спасибо за совет, я думаю этот вариант мне подойдет

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста дополнение к моему вопросу